# Control speed of process

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, subprocess, emulation

more of a general question here. I want to implement small scripts on which I should be able to control the speed of execution, for educational purposes, emulating some real embedded board. The choice of language is between Python (preferred) and C/C++.

My idea is like this: I want to create a base class with a processing speed associated to it, like

```
def myClass:
    MYSPEED = 100 # Instructions/s or anything else

    ...
```

`myClass` should have an associated clock speed with it. Then I may create any

```
def newClass(myClass):
    def func1():
        code
```

and run code in it. However the code in `func1()` should run at the speed of MyClass. Is there any way through threading, `subprocess`, decorators or anything else through which I may accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about slowing down the process in general, essentially limiting the number of assembly instructions per second, then no - there is no direct way to accomplish this.
The computer will always run all processes at full speed.

Your options are basically:

### Emulation

Use an full emulator with speed control, running the OS + whatever process you want to run slow.

### In-code speed control

Include the clock speed handing directly in the code you are writing, e.g. by adding a `clock_tick()` call between each instruction.

Comment: In-code speed control is not feasible as I do not want to make any change at the code.

Do you think I may get what I want using docker images?

Comment: @Ibedogni docker is just encapsulation and not an emulator. The best it can do is limit to a percentage of a cpu core, but that is averaged over time and probably now what you're after. Actually the only emulator I can think of at the moment that actually has HW clock control as a feature is Dosbox, most other emulators are focused on just emulating the functionality as fast as possible.